# How to extend a user's session in MVC 4 forms authentication via AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I'm using Forms Authentication for an internal company website. I authenticate users against the local Active Directory server.

I have my Web.config file set up as follows:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="30" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" defaultUrl="/" />
</authentication>
```

This works fine as long as a user moves to a new page, or refreshes the page they're on. However, much of my UI is based on javascript templating and AJAX, so it's quite possible for a user to be working on a page for longer than 30 minutes.

So, how do I query and/or extend how much time they have remaining in their session via an AJAX call? I don't need help with the AJAX call, just what I'd put in a controller (such as /user/keepalive)

Comment: In order to query you just need to read out the cookie I guess. In order to extend the time, it would suffice to make the call.

Comment: I can't read the cookie directly because it's encrypted. But you're saying that if I just make a call to /user/keepalive at some interval less than 30 minutes, that should automatically extend their session?

Comment: Exactly. Just the fact that you're calling the server again, will extend the session